# Angular 8 create custom elements with Ivy

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements, angular-ivy

I need to create a custom element (web component) using angular 8 enabling ivy. to used with an anther framework, is there any proper documentation for that?

Comment: Not really, but if Ivy ist he only thing you need to know: [Opting into Angular Ivy](https://next.angular.io/guide/ivy#opting-into-angular-ivy).
The more challenging part is to get (build) self contained web components, as this is currently not supported by Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you looking for the Ivy part, if you just want to generate custom component to be used elsewhere, have a look at [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) .

In the end, it will generate a native javascript file that can be embedded with any framework.